# Yii doesn't know about changes on my database

Tags: php, database, yii, oracle10g

I'm quite new to Yii, I've been working for 3 weeks with **Yii** and **Yii** helped me a lot. My app is working fine until my colleagues need to make some changes in the database. They deleted a table named `STORE_PROCESSOR` and create 2 new tables named `BIG_STORE_PROCESSOR` and `SMALL_STORE_PROCESSOR`. They also add a new column to a table.

The problem is when I try to use Gii to create model for these new tables, Gii tells that those tables don't exist in database. What Gii knows is `STORE_PROCESSOR` table still exist in database. `CActiveRecord` also doesn't know about the new column that has been added to a table.

- Is there a way to let Yii know about the changes on my database?

We're using Oracle 10g XE database and Yii 1.1.14

Here's my `config/main.php`

```
<?php

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'Portal Online Store',
    'language'=>'en',
    'theme'=>'default',

    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload'=>array('log'),

    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
    ),

    'modules'=>array(
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'bolu',
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
        ),

    ),

    // application components
    'components'=>array(
        'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        ),
        // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format

        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),      
        // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database

        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString'=>'oci:dbname=152.116.31.148:1521/XE;charset=UTF8',
            //'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
            'password' => '******',
            //'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),


        'errorHandler'=>array(
            // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction'=>'site/error',
        ),
        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                ),
                // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
                /*
                array(
                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                ),
                */
            ),
        ),
    ),

    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params'=>array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
        'timeout'=>'900',
        'timezone'=>'Asia/Jakarta'
    ),
);
```

Comment: Can you show some codes ?

Comment: Sounds like a caching problem with your table definitions.

Comment: Click on another menu item in Gii and click on 'Model' menu item again

Comment: @Raptor I've added my `config\main.php` code

Comment: @Willem Renzema Yeah I've read some sources that said it might be the cache problem. But how do I find the cache? my `protected\runtime` folder only contains application log and gii-1.1.14.  @crafter I've done that and it's still showing the deleted table name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is not in Yii. We're new to Yii and also new to Oracle Database. You have to update the tables named `WWW_TAB_COLUMNS`, `WWW_TAB_CONS`, `WWW_TABLES` in `SQL developer (Oracle DB)`,  once you altering tables. If don't, `Yii` won't know any changes in database. `WWW_TAB_COLUMNS` contains information about all columns that exist in your database. Then, `WWW_TAB_CONS` contains information about all constraints that exist in your database. Last, `WWW_TABLES` contains information about all tables that exist in your database. It looks like web app must see those tables first before doing CRUD Operations

Answer (score 1):

1. you need to get refresh your db schema, run the following code so it gets deleted (make a controller with an action containing the following code ...)

   ```
   public action refreshSchema()
   {
   // Load all tables of the application in the schema
   Yii::app()->db->schema->getTables();
   // clear the cache of all loaded tables
   Yii::app()->db->schema->refresh();
   }
   ```
2. the other easy way is to go to the runtime/cache directory and erase all *.bin files so it will force to create new cache schema.
3. One last way is to refresh the cache of the specific table

   ```
   Yii::app()->db->schema->getTable('tablename', true);
   ```